# Is it possible to load a DLL into the address space not from a file-system file?

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary

I have to create a wrapper DLL that exports some symbols (functions). Within its resources it contains another **encrypted** DLL that actually does the job.

Upon the wrapper DLL initialization it decrypts the original one, saves it in a file, and loads into the address space by `LoadLibrary`. However I'd like to avoid saving this DLL in a file.

I know that this doesn't guarantee a bullet-proof protection, actually one may dump the process virtual memory and see it there. I also know that it's possible to create a file with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` attribute, which ensures this file will be deleted as soon as the process terminates. But still I'd like to know if there's an option to load the DLL "not from a file".

So far I thought about the following:

1. Allocate a virtual memory block with adequate protection (`PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` or `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`). Preferrably at the image preferred base address.
2. Extract/decrypt the DLL image there.
3. If the image base address isn't its preferred address - do the relocation "manually". I.e. - analyze the relocation table and patch the image in-place.
4. Handle the image imports. Load its dependency DLLs and fill symbol addresses.
5. Invoke its initialization function (`DllMain`).

That is, I can do the work of the loader. But unfortunately there are some areas where the DLL loaded by the above trick will behave differently, since it's not a properly-loaded DLL from the OS's perspective. This includes the following:

- The `DllMain` requires the DLL "module handle", which is just its base address. It may use this handle in calls to various API functions, such as `LoadResource`. Those calls will probably fail.
- There will be problems with exception handling. The OS won't see the DLL's `SAFESEH` section, hence its internal exception handling code won't be invoked (it's a 64-bit DLL, means `SAFESEH` is **mandatory** for exception handling).

Here's my question: Is there an API to properly load the DLL into the process address space without the need for it to be in a file? An alternative variant of `LoadLibrary` that works, say, on a file mapping instead of a file-system file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load a DLL which is located in the resources of another image and execute it without needing a file! Take a look at [this article](http://www.joachim-bauch.de), this is exactly what you want. It works, I tried it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought more-or-less. I just wonder if this will suffer from the potential problems I mentioned. I'll test it.

Comment: I have tested in on x86 only, thus I did not test against SAFESEH eiter. Otherwise, this works pretty well as a standard DLL.